# Is there a database of prime numbers of the form ...

Tags: prime-numbers

I was hoping to find an exhaustive list or database of the most common forms of prime numbers that is searchable. By form, I mean 2^p-1 or 6n-1 etcetera. Does anyone know of a good resource? The closest I have come to such a resource is oeis.org.

Answer (score 1):

UTM maintains  [lists of known prime numbers](https://primes.utm.edu/primes/) (e.g. the first [50 million primes](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/) , [5000 largest known primes](http://primes.utm.edu/primes/), etc.).

You could easily take those lists and filter them on your criteria.

Comment: Largest **known** primes, that is.

Comment: @RobertIsrael - Right, updated.